# Qual è l'origine dell'esclamazione "allora"?

Tags: etymology, exclamations

In frasi del tipo: "Allora! Stai più attento!"
che provenienza ha l'espressione?

Answer (score 6):

Nell'[enciclopedia Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/segnali-discorsivi_(Enciclopedia-dell%27Italiano)/) c'è una definizione generica sui segnali discorsivi.

> Lo studio dei segnali discorsivi ha un’essenziale dimensione diacronica (per es., Sweetser 1990; Traugott & Dasher 2002; Cuenca 2007), dato che diversi valori semantici e pragmatici dei segnali discorsivi si sono sviluppati nel tempo da un nucleo primario centrale (cfr. § 1).
>
> Si tratta in parte di un fenomeno di ➔ grammaticalizzazione. Per es., per allora, a partire dal valore temporale e dalla funzione referenziale originaria, si sono sviluppate funzioni interazionali e inferenziali (quelle tipiche, ad es., della costruzione condizionale se … allora), molto diffuse nell’italiano contemporaneo (come negli esempi 21, 22, 24, 25), accanto agli usi temporali (anaforico, nel caso dell’es. 23).

Non so se sia possibile trovare una motivazione precisa per la perdita di valore temporale di *allora* ed altre parole simili (certamente non ne ho io le competenze), ma il passaggio dalla costruzione condizionale qui citata potrebbe essere:

[se hai terminato/se posso parlare] Allora...-> presa di turno -> generico richiamo di attenzione (il tuo esempio)

Answer (score 1):

Proviene dal latino

**ad illam horam** ‘a quell'ora’

(ref.: [sito](https://unaparolaalgiorno.it/significato/A/allora))

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE!

Comment: I think we should make an effort to explain the reason of downvotes, specially with new contributors.

Comment: L'etimologia è nota. La domanda riguarda un uso specifico di *allora*.

Comment: Grazie per l'etimologia Nello, in effetti ero interessato al suo uso come esclamazione, perché a differenza di altre esclamazioni di uso comune non vedo nessun legame con invocazioni, profanità o volgarità in generale

Comment: @egreg Mi sembra un buon motivo per dare un -1 alla domanda che è imprecisa semmai, non a questa risposta.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Non fare deduzioni scorrette.

Comment: @egreg Perché la mia sarebbe una deduzione scorretta? Il mio argomento è che se la domanda chiede *qual è l'etimologia dell'esclamazione "allora"*, non vedo motivo di prendersela con una risposta che fornisce l'etimologia di "allora". Se OP voleva chiedere *da dove proviene l'uso di "allora" come esclamazione*, avrebbe dovuto essere più chiaro.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni La deduzione scorretta sta nel voto negativo che non ho dato. Comunque ho corretto la domanda.